# Graphic InterfaceTkinter Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, interface

I´m having a problem with my interface using Tkinter in Python. I would like to put the phrase "Primeira cesta" and the button "Aplicar", at the top of the interface, not at the bottom. After that, I would like that comes the dropdown.

Can anybody help me, please?

## Code

from tkinter import*

class Application():
    def **init**(self, master):

```
    mainframe = Frame(root)
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0,sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    mainframe.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)

    #color1


    self.widget1 = Frame(master)
    self.widget1.pack(side=TOP)
    self.msg = Label(self.widget1, text="Primeira cesta")
    self.msg["font"]=("Times New Roman", "12", "italic", "bold")
    self.msg.pack()


    self.aplicar=Button(self.widget1)
    self.aplicar["text"]="Aplicar"
    self.aplicar["font"]=("Calibri","10")
    self.aplicar["width"]=5
    self.aplicar["command"]=self.mudarTexto
    self.aplicar.pack()




    #Dropdown1

    # Create a Tkinter variable
    tkvar = StringVar(root)
    tkvar2 = StringVar(root)

    # Dictionary with options
    cores = { 'Amarelo','Azul','Verde','Vermelho'}
    formatos = {'2x1','2x2','2x3','2x4'}
    tkvar.set('Cores') # set the default option
    tkvar2.set('Formatos')

    popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *cores)
    label1=Label(mainframe, text="Escolha uma cor")
    label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)



    popupMenu2 = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar2, *formatos)
    label2=Label(mainframe, text="Escolha um formato")
    label2.grid(row=3,column=1)
    popupMenu2.grid(row = 4, column =1)

    # on change dropdown value
    def change_dropdown(*args):
        print( tkvar.get() )

    def change_dropdown2(*args):
        print( tkvar2.get() )

    # link function to change dropdown
    tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)
    tkvar2.trace('w', change_dropdown2)



def mudarTexto(self):
    if self.msg["text"]=="Primeira cesta":
        self.msg["text"]="A primeira cesta foi configurada"
    else:
        self.msg["text"]="Primeira cesta"
```

root=Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4aYJ.png)

Comment: Order your frames. Looks like you are having issues with your frames parents being diffrent. Try setting both Frames parents to root, then pack/grid self.widget1 before mainframe.

Comment: Change to `Frame(mainframe)` or consider to use [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) instead of `.pack(...`